# difference between app.use('/users', usersRouter); and require(./routes/users)(app)?

Tags: express

In the express tutorial from mozilla,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/skeleton_website

they write

```
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

In other tutorials, they write something like this,

```
require('./routes/authRoutes')(app);
```

Are the two pretty much equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code for the other tutorials that you mentioned I cannot be sure exactly how they consume the `app` object that is passed to the imported code, but I suspect that whatever code is implemented in the `.routes/authRoutes` module simply connects a router object to the specified `app` object. This would most likely be done in the same way as the code that you provided from the Mozilla Express tutorial.

In both cases, a route handler is being defined and then registered as a handler for any routes that match the specified route. In the case  that you mentioned that route would be the `/users` route. So the `usersRouter` object would have a number of route handlers defined, for example, for routes `/abc` and `/def`. So registering the `usersRouter` object as a route handler for the `/users` route would mean that the routes `/users/abc` and `/users/def` would be handled.